# How to provide login authentication for Web API in Xamarin App?

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-web-api, authentication, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin Forms application and new to providing login authentication of the application. I have completed the design part of the application with using Entries for user id and password and button for Submit. Also, i am having web API and for authentication. Now how to connect that Web API in xamarin forms application for login.

Please guide or provide some use full samples...

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Are you using .net core for your API?

Comment: @NullHypothesis Yes...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've built out your authentication API already, and that you can make Fiddler or Postman calls directly to your controller, pass in a set of credentials, and return back a JWT / bearer token that you can then use for authenticated calls?

At this point, it's relatively simple then as you'll want to use build a proxy layer / API layer to make calls out to your API. These calls will simply mirror the ones you've made in Fiddler/Postman/your proxy of choice.

I used Refit to achieve this:

https://github.com/reactiveui/refit

Specifically, you can see on the "Setting request headers" section how they easily encapsulate it for you to pass your token.

Of course, your initial call should be to login, and then once logged in, take the JWT response back from your controller, set the token in your Keychain, and then pull it out of Keychain to set in the header.

Let me know specific questions you have? For example, which of the following do you need more info on?

1. Sending and parsing a response (serializing the response) from your Login action to set/assign a token in keychain?
2. Saving the token, and setting it in a header for subsequent calls?
3. Building a proxy layer using a framework like Refit to make generic outbound calls?

Comment: Thanks for the response.First of all, I am new to Xamarin authentication and not aware about at all. My question is how to validate the user id and password in Login click button. Please provide some examples samples or code snippet for it...